# matlab: how to plot different errorbars in bar graph

Tags: matlab, plot

i want to plot different errorbars `std_a/b/c` in my bar graph

```
a=5;  std_a=0.9;  
b=6;  std_b=0.5;
c=7;  std_c=0.2;

%plot
bar([a,b,c]);
errorbar([a,b,c],[std_a,std_b,std_c]);
```

somehow this is not working. how can get for each bar the correct errorbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. `errorbar` by default plots a line and adds errorbars to it, and if you haven't called `hold on` or `hold all` it will overwrite what you already have. If you just want the error bars and not lines between them, give it a plot format that only plots points, like `r.`:

```
bar([a,b,c]);
hold on
errorbar([a,b,c],[std_a,std_b,std_c],'r.');
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to improve location of the error bars on x axis because for more than one data series the bars appear side by side, while the error bars may appear one on top of the other.

for data with two columns and serr (standard error in my case) of the same size I used a shift to the left and right of +-1.4 (see gap in the code below).

```
gap=0.14;
X=1:length(data);
X=[X'-gap,X'+gap];
errorbar(X,data,serr,'k.');
```

you can specify a third input argument of zeros the same size of serr, if you want to minimise the bottom bars so that only top error bars show.